# How to optimize a macros which is running on large number of records?

Tags: vba, excel, optimization, macros

I have come up with a macros for populating the Super Manager against employees. I am unable to perform this macros against large sets of data and Excel Hangs. I assume this code isn't quite optimized.

A few Requirements and Pre Requisites:

1. Manager ID Column will be the first column ie column A and the Employee ID column is the second column ie column B in the sheet.
2. Super managers will not be populated in Sheet 1 ie no record of super managers should exist in the Sheet 1 except for their ids mapped against Manager ID of other employees
3. Super managers will be populated in Sheet 2 with the same order as in the attached sheet  ie. Super Manager Id | Super Manager Name| Whatever extra data fields needed.
4. Once the pre requisites are taken care of please click on "Macros" button and run the macros called: Main_Function_SuperManager.
5. The super manager details will be listed in column S and T respectively of Sheet 1.

Here is my Macros:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main_Function_SuperManager()
Dim i, re
Root_Parent
Replace
Replace_Name
i = 1
    While Cells(i, 22) <> ""

         Cells(i, 22) = ""
         Cells(i, 23) = ""
         i = i + 1

    Wend
End Sub
Sub Root_Parent()
    Dim i, re, k
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Set re = Range("B:B").Find(Cells(i, 1))
        If re Is Nothing Then
            Set re = Range("V:V").Find(Cells(i, 1))
            If re Is Nothing Then
                k = k + 1
                Cells(k, 22) = Cells(i, 1)
                Cells(k, 23) = "Super Manager"
                findchild Cells(k, 22).Value, k
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
Sub findchild(parent, ByRef k)
 Dim i, s, re
 i = 1
    While Cells(i, 2) <> ""
    s = i
        Do
            Set re = Range("B:B").Find(Cells(s, 1))
            If re Is Nothing Then
                If Cells(s, 1) = parent Then
                k = k + 1
                Cells(k, 22) = Cells(i, 2)
                Cells(k, 23) = Cells(s, 1)
                End If
                Exit Do
            Else
                s = re.Row
            End If
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Sub Replace()
    Dim i, re, s
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, 22) <> ""
        Set re = Range("B:B").Find(Cells(i, 22))
        If re Is Nothing Then
        Cells(10, 24) = ""
        Else
         s = re.Row
         Cells(s, 19) = Cells(i, 23)
        End If
        i = i + 1

    Wend
End Sub

Sub Replace_Name()
    Dim i, re, s
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, 19) <> ""
        Set re = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(Cells(i, 19))
        If re Is Nothing Then
        Cells(10, 24) = ""
        Else
         s = re.Row
         Cells(i, 20) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(s, 2)
        End If
        i = i + 1

    Wend
End Sub
```

This code helps me parse down a large list of data and list the highest level root nodes to the child and grand child nodes.

My data structure looks as follows:

```
MANAGER ID|EMP ID|NAME|GRADE|MANAGER|<some other fields>|SUPER MANAGER ID|SUPER MANAGER NAME
```

Really looking forward to tips to optimize this code such that i can perform the function on large data sets.

In essence I wish to populate the child nodes with their respective highest level roots nodes such that all child nodes have a root level data/parent mapped to them.

Comment: From the look of this, you may be better off using a SQL statement to update your sheet. It should be fast and be able to handle what you are after, and in my opinion is a cleaner approach. If for nothing else, it's a good technique to know more about. Here's an article from MSDN on the topic. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The main drag in this code is the constant reading and writing out/in the worksheet. If you work with the data in variables, the code will be very fast. In fact, code like yours should finish in seconds (or less) when working this way.

I have drafted an example inspired in one of the subs in your code, it may not work "out of the box" as I don't understand your data structure perfectly, but the most important point is: get all the data from the workbook just once and put it back there just once (that was done in the lines with 3 *). The logical operations should be done in memory (with the data stored in variables).

```
Sub Replace()
    Dim i, re, s, row_num, col_num, data_initial(), data_final()
    Dim WS_1 As Worksheet

    'defines the worksheet object
    Set WS_1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'get where do the data range begins and ends
    row_num = WS_1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    col_num = WS_1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Row

    '***dump the data from the worksheet to memory all in once
    data_initial = WS_1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(Row - 1, col).Value

    'create a blank matrix where the output will be placed
    ReDim data_final(LBound(data_initial, 1) To UBound(data_initial, 1), LBound(data_initial, 2) To UBound(data_initial, 2))

    'you do your work whith the data, this part may not be coherent since I dont understand your data very well
    i = 1
    While i <= UBound(data_initial, 1)
        If data_initial(i, 22) = "" Then
            data_final(i, 24) = ""
        Else
            s = 1
            Do Until data_initial(i, 2) = data_initial(i, 22)
                s = s + 1
            Loop

            data_final(i, 24) = data_initial(i, 23)

            i = i + 1
    Wend

    '***dump the data into the worksheet (again, just once)
    WS_1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LBound(data_initial, 1) To UBound(data_initial, 1), LBound(data_initial, 2) To UBound(data_initial, 2)).Value = data_final

End Sub
```